# Implement Fractional knapsack

Tags: c++, algorithm, stl, knapsack-problem

I am trying to implement Fractional knapsack by first sorting the elements by the ratio of value of the object to weight of the object. I am using a vector of pairs where the first element of pair is the value of the object and second element of pair is weight. `compbyrat` function is for comparing the vector elements by the ratio of value to weight. I am getting a run-time error with the below code.Can anyone help me find the mistake?

```
#include <iostream>
#include<algorithm>
#include<vector>
#include<utility>
using namespace std;
bool compbyrat(const pair<long long int,long long int> &a, const pair<long long int,long long int> &b)
{
    return ((double)a.first/(double)a.second)< ((double) b.first/(double) b.second) ;
}
int main() {
    long long int n, weight;
    vector<pair<long long int,long long int> > v;
    cin>>n>>weight;
    for(long long int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        cin>>v[i].first>>v[i].second;
    }

    sort(v.begin(), v.end(), compbyrat);
    long long int currentweight = 0, ans =0;
    for(long long int i =0; i < n && currentweight < weight; i++){
        if(currentweight + v[i].second <= weight){
            ans = ans + v[i].first;
        }
        else{
            ans = ans + (((double)v[i].first/(double)v[i].second) * (weight -currentweight));
        }
    }
    cout<<ans;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: At first, you haven't initialized your vector. Add a "v.resize(n)" line after you've read n and weight. Accessing the elements of an empty vector is an UB.

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should \[edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Comment: Thank you. Got it. Started coding in C++ after a gap of 2 years, have forgotten many things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve it with some modifications. The code is below,

```
#include <iostream>
#include<algorithm>
#include<vector>
#include<utility>
#include<iomanip>
using namespace std;
bool compbyrat(const pair<long long int,long long int> &a, const pair<long long int,long long int> &b)
{
    return ((double)((double)a.first/(double)a.second)> (double)((double) b.first/(double) b.second)) ;
}
int main() {
    long long int n, weight;
    cin>>n>>weight;

    vector<pair<long long int,long long int> > v(n+2);
    for(long long int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        cin>>v[i].first>>v[i].second;
    }

    sort(v.begin(), v.end(), compbyrat);
    //cout<<v[0].first;
    long long int currentweight = 0;
    double ans = 0.0000;
    for(long long int i =0; i < n && currentweight < weight; i++){
        if(currentweight + v[i].second <= weight){
            ans = ans + v[i].first;
            currentweight = currentweight + v[i].second;
            //cout<<v[i].first<<" "<<v[i].second<<endl;
        }
        else{
            ans = ans + ((double)((double)v[i].first/(double)v[i].second) * (weight -currentweight));
            currentweight = currentweight + v[i].second;
        }


    }
    cout<<fixed << setprecision(4)<<ans;
    return 0;
}
```